# Jekyll/Liquid Nav links on different pages?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm working with Jekyll to create a blog and was wondering how I can use liquid to have different links for the nav on different pages. I've done this before using Shopify, but for some reason its not the same with Jekyll.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           {% if page.handle contains 'blogs' %}
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           {% else %}
                <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
           {% endif %}
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `page.handle` in Jekyll. You can try to use `page.path` instead.